# CEWP script works but causes slideshow to "jump" between transition?

Tags: web-part, cewp

I had an issue with the slideshow webpart and extra whitespace on the sides and top. I found a code that successfully removes it and makes the images full size as I wanted, but sometimes when transitioning between images it "jumps" causing the whole page to move momentarily (i.e. if you're trying to click something during the transition jump you might click the wrong thing since whole page moves).

I took the script and created a txt file and saved it to Site Assets. Then added a CEWP to the page and linked it to the text sheet.

Can someone please let me know what part of this code is causing it to jump instead of smooth transitioning? Or let me know what I need to add to make it stop? Thanks.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


    function SlideshowObjectInitializer() {

      ShowPic = (function(ShowPicOrig) {
      return function() {

           var ssObj = arguments[0];  //SlideShow object
           var curPicIdx=ssObj.index; //current picture index

           ShowPicOrig.apply(this, arguments); //call original ShowPic

           //apply some changes to display original picture in SlideShow control
           ssObj.image.src = ssObj.linkArray[curPicIdx]; //display original image instead of web image
           //change picture & container size to auto instead of fixed (by default web image size is used)
             ssObj.image.setAttribute('height','100%'); 
             ssObj.image.setAttribute('width','100%'); 
             var cell = ssObj.cell; 
             cell.style.width = 'auto';
             cell.style.height = 'auto';
             cell.style.display = '';
             var pcell = ssObj.cell.parentNode; 
           pcell.style.width = 'auto';
             pcell.style.height = 'auto';
      };
  })(ShowPic);

}  


ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SlideshowObjectInitializer, 'imglib.js');
</script>
```

Comment: Does this behavior happen across all browsers? Are you using a custom master page?

Comment: No it only happens on this page with the slideshow. I'm not using a custom master page. Do you know if there's anything specific to the code in the CEWP that is causing it?